# Perform AJAX request on an interval until appropriate response is received

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am performing an AJAX request using jQuery, which is working fine, but the server response varies between an XML response with a URL, and an XML response with no content.

Effectively, both these responses qualify the request as 'successful' or 'done', so in handling the 'done' event for my AJAX request, I'd like to verify that the response is not empty, and if it is, try the AJAX request again after a delay.

I was looking into jQuery promises but I am not sure if that is quite what I want, but if it is, please provide an easy to understand example.

This is what I would like:

```
    function(name, location){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",
            data: { name: name, location: location }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            if (msg.length < 1) {
                setTimeout(
                   // Perform this request again
                , 500);
            } else {
                // Go on
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a guess

```
//here´s a function called runAgain, waiting for two parameters, the timeout function will execute it again
function runAgain(name, location){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "some.php",
                data: { name: name, location: location }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                if (msg.length < 1) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                       runAgain(name,location)
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    // Go on
                }
            });
}

//This function runs when the document is ready, an calls the runAgain function 
$(function(){

   var name= "?";
   var location = "?";
    runAgain(name,location);
});
```